# (heroku dyno error)Suddenly the app is crushed

Tags: heroku

Django web is deployed on Heroku and the site is working fine.
But sometimes the app crashes suddenly. When this problem occurred the last time, it was judged as a setting problem and modified settings.json.
However, the app crash occurred again.

The error log is as follows:

```
2021-04-28T20:09:33.420089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-04-28T20:09:33.422509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-04-28T20:09:33.971825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-04-28T20:09:34.107327+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 20:09:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-04-28T20:09:34.107340+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 20:09:34 +0000] [34] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 34)
2021-04-28T20:09:34.107340+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 20:09:34 +0000] [33] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 33)
2021-04-28T20:09:34.207793+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-28 20:09:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-04-28T20:09:34.290292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-04-29T00:13:03.197376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host='' request_id='' fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-04-28T20:09:33.422509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
```

see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic
> in a 30-minute period, it will sleep. In addition to the web dyno
> sleeping, the worker dyno (if present) will also sleep.
>
> Free web dynos do not consume free dyno hours while sleeping.
>
> If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active
> again after a short delay (assuming your account has free dyno hours
> available).

It did not crash. It went to sleep due to receiving no web traffic in a 30 minute period.

If you want it to stay awake you either need to redefine the process type to anything other than `web` but you will lose the web functionality. Or you ping your website periodically so it stays awake.

Comment: An app crash occurred after the server fell asleep. So I decided that the cause was in dyno.

"2021-04-29T00:13:03.197376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host='' request_id='' fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https" 

Does it mean this error wasn't caused by dyno?

Comment: You are trying to access the server when it no longer exists because it went to sleep. So you are accessing nothing. It going to sleep it an intentional behavior. Look at who is posting the logs. There is `heroku[web]` the parent of your application. `app[web]` this is your actual application. And then here is `heroku[router]` this merely forwards the web traffic to your `web` dyno. The `web` dyno did not crash.

Comment: Oh I understand. I should refer to the advice and find the cause. Thanks for the advice!